# Docker failed push image to registry : received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: docker, http, docker-for-windows, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to push an tagged image to my local registry but it failed.

I'm using **Docker Desktop for Windows**.

C:\Users\XXXX>**`docker push localhost:5000/test`**

```
   The push refers to repository [localhost:5000/test]
    687914c021dc: Pushed
    922472a9958a: Pushed
    273db4b66a2d: Skipped foreign layer
    received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

In the logs I have this ;

```
192.168.18.89 - - [16/May/2019:12:52:02 +0000] "POST /v2/test/blobs/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 500 253 "" "docker/18.09.2 go/go1.10.6 git-commit/6247962 os/windows arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.09.2 \\(windows\\))"
time="2019-05-16T12:52:02.0881065Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code=unknown err.detail="filesystem: truncate /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/test/_uploads/74edc5c6-375f-4482-a9cc-29e982720bc1/startedat: permission denied" err.message="unknown error" go.version=go1.11.2 http.request.host="localhost:5001" http.request.id=73b1b50c-06e0-4ff0-82bc-995b8ba20209 http.request.method=POST http.request.remoteaddr="192.168.18.89:52000" http.request.uri="/v2/test/blobs/uploads/" http.request.useragent="docker/18.09.2 go/go1.10.6 git-commit/6247962 os/windows arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.09.2 \(windows\))" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=27.963ms http.response.status=500 http.response.written=253 vars.name=test
```

Docker Desktop Community for Windows // 
Version : 2.0.0.3 (31259) //
Engine: 18.09.2

Comment: Include the command and/or compose file you used to start the registry server.

Comment: @BMitch I didn't use another file... the daemon.json in the config folder didn't change
`{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": true
}`

Comment: I solved it with `--allow-nondistributable-artifacts: localhost:5000`